# Regular Expression not working C++

Tags: c++, regex

im trying to use a regular expression to ensure the heading entered for an aircraft is between o and 360, but i cant get it to work.

```
std::regex headingCheck{"^([0-9]|1[0-9]2[0])$"};
    bool match = false;
    while (!match)
    {
        if (std::regex_match(heading, headingCheck))
        {
            heading_ = heading;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid heading, can only be between 0 and 360 degrees" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

#

```
//Heading can only be between 0-360?
    if (heading >= 0 && heading <= 360)
    {
        heading_ = heading;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect heading, heading can only be between 0 and 360" << std::endl;
    }
```

Should i do this instead? Is it as accurate/reliable?

Comment: Try casing to an int, check the range? - This is not a job for a RE.

Comment: Validating range by regex is doable but would be order of magnitude more complex that simply convert to `int` and check range. Use regex just to validate that number is provided.

Comment: void Aircraft::SetHeading(int heading)
{
 //Heading can only be between 0-360?
 //Set up regular expression, compare it to input
 std::regex headingCheck{"^([0-9]|1[0-9]2[0])$"};
 bool match = false;
 while (!match)
 {
  if (std::regex_match(heading, headingCheck))
  {
   heading_ = heading;
  }
  else
  {
   std::cout << "Invalid heading, can only be between 0 and 360 degrees" << std::endl;
  }
 }
 
}  Its for a setter method, what do you guys mean check range?

Comment: @MurrackCarn Don't post code in comments - it's unreadable. [Edit] the question instead.

Comment: Sorry, im new here not used to the way of things, my bad

Comment: We mean convert that string to `int` and check that `int` if it is in range like `if( angle < 0 or angle > 360 ) // error` and your `heading_` should be `int` anyway

Comment: Heading is already an int, so it doesnt need converted. I can do it through a simple if statement but i thought doing a regex instead would somehow be better

Comment: @MurrackCarn If you're receiving the value as an int I'm struggling to imagine why you'd even consider using a regex. You say "a simple if statement" as if "simple" is in some way negative. Sometimes (often) the simple way to do something is also the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want regex (though this is not optimal) you can use the following expression:

```
std::regex re{ "^[0-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]$|^[1-2][0-9][0-9]$|^3[0-5][0-9]$|^360$" };
std::string headings[5] = { "0","15","390","360","23883" };

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << "Heading " << headings[i] << " is " << (std::regex_match(headings[i], re) ? "valid" : "invalid") << std::endl;
```

First part matches 0-9, second part matches 10-99, third part matches 100-299, fourth part matches 300-359, last matches 360. Prints:

```
Heading 0 is valid
Heading 15 is valid
Heading 390 is invalid
Heading 360 is valid
Heading 23883 is invalid
```

Comment: Heading 275 is ... invalid?  Hmm.  Not quite.

Comment: Good catch! Edited